# Why is "wget -r -e robots=off http://ccachicago.org" not acting recursively?

Tags: wget, download

I am trying to recursively download `http://ccachicago.org`, and am getting exactly one file, the root `index.html`, downloaded.

I've looked at [Download recursively with wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25340/download-recursively-with-wget) and started using the recommended `-e robots=off`, but it still behaves the same.

How, with `wget` or some other tool, can I download a copy of the site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108709/16279)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are asking `wget` to do a *recursive* download of `http://ccachicago.org`, but this URL doesn't provide any direct content. instead it is just a re-direct to `http://www.ccachicago.org` (which you haven't told `wget` to fetch recursively)..

if you tell `wget` to download the correct URL it will work:

```
wget -r -e robots=off http://www....
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because wget defaults to only doing recursive download within the hostname that you used when you started.

http://ccachicago.org issues a redirect to http://www.ccachicago.org. Since all further links are under `www.ccachicago.org`, wget will consider those links as being off-site and won't follow them.

The easiest solution here is of course to start with `wget -r http://www.ccachicago.org`.

You could also add www.ccachicago.org to the list of domains to follow:

```
wget -r -D www.ccachicago.org http://ccachicago.org
```

For the future, you can find this kind of information by adding the debug flag. When I did that, I got

```
Deciding whether to enqueue "http://www.ccachicago.org/".
This is not the same hostname as the parent's (www.ccachicago.org and ccachicago.org).
Decided NOT to load it.
Redirection "http://www.ccachicago.org/" failed the test.
```